# UDP multicast does not work when sending from wire to wireless

Tags: networking, udp, multicast

I implemented UDP Multicast through C++, which works very well.

but Strangely, I have a problem testing it between my laptop (wireless) and my PC (wired).
using the same network, the laptop is connected via Wi-Fi through the router, and the PC is connected via a wired LAN.

as a result of my test, if I send Multicast packets from PC to laptop, it will not be received properly.
Conversely, when a Multicast packet is send from laptop to PC, it is received well.

code used the same code, so there seems to be no coding problem.

Why is the network working like this?

Comment: Multicast and broadcast are sent at the slowest possible rate on Wi-Fi in order to be able to be received by all hosts, even distant hosts that can only use the slowest possible rate. If the wired PC sends at a fast, wired rate to Wi-Fi, many packets will be dropped.

Comment: @RonMaupin thank you answer, It's a characteristic of the standard Wi-Fi design...?

Comment: Yes, that is part of the standard in order that all Wi-Fi hosts, including distant hosts, can receive all multicast and broadcast. Some WAPs can be configured to change multicast packets to unicast packets to each host, but that takes a lot more time (one multicast packet converted to a unicast packet for each host, and they must be sent one at a time), increasing the time with more hosts. It may be possible to configure the slowest speed on the WAP to be faster, but that will limit the usable distance. Multicast on Wi-Fi does not work well.